# reading a JSON file in spark-scala from command line

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Code:

```
val path = "/test/path"
var df = spark.read.format("json").load(path)
```

This works perfectly fine in a zepplin notebook. But when I try to run the same code using command line i get the following error.

```
spark-shell
--same code--

error: not found: value spark
```

This is the first time I am trying to work with spark from cmd line. Any suggestions on what am I missing would be helpful

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @ÁlvaroValencia Version: 1.6.0

Comment: For all the geniuses who down voted the question, thanks:). There is always someone to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may happen because you are using an older Spark version. Try using `sc` (`SparkContext`) instead of `spark` (`SparkSession`), that was introduced in Spark 2.0.0.

Also, you are trying to create a `Dataframe`. In order to do that in Spark < 2.0.0, you need a `SQLContext` that you can create in this way:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

And then you can read your JSON file:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(path)
```

Anyways I'd suggest you update your Spark version to the latest version.